# Can any one help me to understand this?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm new to shell scripting and I Can't understand those lines:

```
wc -l $x|sed 's/\s\+/|/g'

rc=`echo "$BTEQ_OUT"|grep "RC (return code)"| sed 's/ //g' | cut -d '=' -f2|tr -d "\r\n "`;
```

Comment: You have to indent your code by four spaces or put it between lines with three backticks (`\`\`\``) each.

Comment: Also, you have to be more specific about what you don't understand.

Comment: Maybe you should write, what exactly these line should accomplish and why you'd like to run it

Comment: For explaining shell try https://explainshell.com https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo+%22%24BTEQ_OUT%22%7Cgrep+%22RC+%28return+code%29%22%7C+sed+%27s%2F+%2F%2Fg%27+%7C+cut+-d+%27%3D%27+-f2%7Ctr+-d+%22%5Cr%5Cn+%22

Comment: Without knowing what's in `$x` or `$BTEQ_OUT`, it's hard to tell what exactly is going on anyway.

Comment: $x is the file that I will count the lines from and $BTEQ_OUT has the log info

Answer (score 1):

```
wc -l $x|sed 's/\s\+/|/g'
```

wc is a tools used for counting, with the `-l` flag, this will count the lines in a file or a string.

`$x` is the variable holding probably a file name to be passed into `wc`

`|` called 'pipe' passes the output of the command before as the input into the command after

sed is another scripting tool used to edit text in files.

`'s/\s\+/|/g'` is regex which globally (g) substitutes  any number of white space chars with pipe symbols '|'

This program does the following

Count how many lines are in $x and whatever you output replace empty characters with pipe symbols.

The fact that they expect multiple outputs from `wc -l` hints that `$x` might store more than one file ...

I'd suggest looking into what some of the other commands are and what they do, and how they interact. List below

```
echo 
tr
cut
pipe
```

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13 ... I need to get better with formatting

Answer (score 1):

When you see a long pipeline, one useful technique for understanding it is to execute it piece by piece:

1. first, what's in `$x`?

   ```
   echo $x
   ```

   is that the name of a file?

   ```
   ls -l $x
   ```
2. what does `wc` do?

   ```
   wc -l $x
   ```
3. ok, what does the sed part do? (note, `\s` requires GNU sed)

   ```
   wc -l $x | sed 's/\s\+/|/g'
   ```

Similarly:

```sh
echo "$BTEQ_OUT"
echo "$BTEQ_OUT"|grep "RC (return code)"
echo "$BTEQ_OUT"|grep "RC (return code)"| sed 's/ //g'
echo "$BTEQ_OUT"|grep "RC (return code)"| sed 's/ //g' | cut -d '=' -f2
echo "$BTEQ_OUT"|grep "RC (return code)"| sed 's/ //g' | cut -d '=' -f2|tr -d "\r\n ";
```